# Where is the html5 local database located on a client machine?

Tags: html

Am playing around with html5 local storage on different browsers (Firefox, Opera, Safari & Chrome) and am just wondering where is the location for the local database that i create using "**opendatabase**".

Can i change the location of this database?

Gath

Answer (score 3):

It will be stored in the user's profile directory somewhere, but the exact location would be different for each browser on each platform (e.g. Firefox vs. Chrome vs. Safari, etc and Windows vs. Linux vs. Mac OS X, etc).

Is there any reason in particular that you want to know, or just curiosity? For example, I  believe Firefox stores it in:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile-name>\webappsstore.sqlite
```

Comment: Yes, i want to look and know which format this database is, and play with it more...

Answer (score 0):

Chrome C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases